# IIS Blocking requests intermittantly until IISRESET

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have another weird issue.

Here's the scenario:

Multiple clients
1 Web server
1 Database server (SQL)

The site works 90% of the time.

Every now and again, users complain the site hangs. I checked it myself and I get Internet Explorer just waiting for the page. No message, no error, nothing. Just waiting.

I'm accesssing the site from a client machine using its name : http://myserver/somevirtualdirectory/default.aspx

Here's the kicker thoug. When connecting to the server via an RDP and browsing to http://localhost/somevirtualdirectory/default.aspx, the site works fine...

I've then also tried to from the client to do a Telnet to port 80 on that server, and yes, it is able to connect to the server, but when doing a GET /test.html command, it gives a Internal Server error 500..

I can always ping the server.. it's definitely up.

The only thing that eventually resolves the problem is an IISRESET or App pool recycle.

My site is running on a Integrated .net 2.0 app pool which uses the Integrated Managed Pipeline.

I've also turned on Failed Request tracing, and it's not actually logging a 500 server error.

Any advice will be helpful.. The problem is intermittant as I said, so very difficult to troubleshoot.

If this was Kerberos related, wouldn't it just not work EVER?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but here goes... BUMP

Comment: I experience this alot. Makes development very slow ... I believe the problem is related to the client, as restarting IE alone also solves the problem. Something to do with a dangling TCP connection?